# Parallax Mouse Movement Help, JQuery, HTML, CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am still a beginner with JQuery and I took it upon myself to figure out a parallax background (I believe this is referred to as a parallax effect) using mousemove. I am using `event.pageX` to create a variable that is later used in setting the background position.

It works but the code is defiantly novice level. Every time I refresh the page I need to move the mouse for the background to start the parallax effect - so, for example, the background starts with at 50% 0% and when I move the mouse it goes to 10.5% 0% and is smooth after that first initial mouse movement.

I was wondering if there was a way to automatically call the `mousemove` function on page load. Or is there a better way to reformat the code for what I am trying to do?

#### JS

```
$('.background').on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    var Xparallax = (event.pageX / 300)
    $('.background').css({
        'background-position' : Xparallax + '% 15%'
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="background" style=""></div>
```

#### CSS

```
div.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url("/images/bg3.jpg");
    background-position: 50% 15%;
    background-size: 125%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var Xparallax = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.background').css({
        'background-position' : Xparallax + '% 15%'
    });
})
```

Comment: Cool effect but I want the mouse to effect where the background is positioned. Here are two images [link] (http://puu.sh/ipMV4.jpg) [link] (http://puu.sh/ipMSg.jpg). So basically what you gave be but using mouse movement, I already have the code I just need to fix the bug so that the first initial movement does not make the background jump. The easiest way I thought was to call the movemouse function manually on load but I don't know how too.

Comment: Make a jsfdille, and i'll try to help you :) !